# Insert variable into string at random position

Tags: php

See this code:

```
<?php

$a = rand(1, 10000000000);
$b = "abcdefghi";

?>
```

How can I insert `$b` into a random position of `$a`?

Comment: Define "casual position". Do you mean a random position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming "casual" means random:

```
<?php
$a = rand(1, 10000000000);
$b = "abcdefghi";

//get a random position in a
$randPos = rand(0,strlen($a));
//insert $b in $a
$c = substr($a, 0, $randPos).$b.substr($a, $randPos);

var_dump($c);
?>
```

above code working: http://codepad.org/VCNBAYt1

Edit: had the vars backwards. I read "insert a into b,

Comment: @AldoHolm I read the OP backwards, the original code would insert $a into $b. fixed the code so it does $b into $a.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could by treating $a as a string and concatenating it with $b:

```
$a = rand(1, 1000000);
$b= "abcd";
$pos = rand(0, strlen($a));
$a =  substr($a, 0, $pos).$b.substr($a, $pos, strlen($a)-$pos);
```

and the results:

```
a=525019
pos=4
a=5250abcd19

a=128715
pos=5
a=12871abcd5
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put {$b} on top of {$a} so that you can insert it to {$b}..
eg:

```
<?php
   $b = "abcdefghi";
   $a = rand(1, 10000000000);
   $a .= $b;
   echo $a;
?>
```

Comment: what exactly does the order the variables are defined have to do with anything? As long as both variables are defined by the time you use them, order doesn't matter.

Comment: Tnks but this isn't random position

Answer (score 0):

Sth like  this :

```
<?php
$position = GetRandomPosition();  // you will have to implement this function
if($position >= strlen($a) - 1) {
    $a .= $b; 
} else {
    $str = str_split($a, $position);
    $a = $str[0] . $b . implode(array_diff($str, array($str[0])));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast $a to string, then use [strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) to get the length of $a. Use rand, with with the length of $a as the maximum, to get a random position within $a. Then use [substr_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) to insert $b into $a at the position you've just randomized.